# Constrained Delaunay Triangulation with curve boundary

Tags: cgal

Does CGAL only support Constrained Delaunay Triangulation (CDT) for Planar Straight Line Graph (PSLG) now?
What about a curve boundary, like a circle or ellipse? I tried to discretize the curve boundary manually, but the element quality is not satisfactory.

Thanks